# Choose between 2 defined numbers randomly

Tags: java, random

So I have this piece of code

```
if (x >= gameView.getWidth()) { //if gone of the right side of screen
    x = x - gameView.getWidth(); //Reset x
    y = random.nextInt(gameView.getHeight());
    xSpeed = 
    ySpeed = 
}
```

but I need to get both `xSpeed` and `ySpeed` to choose between two values, either '10' or '-10' and only those two numbers, nothing in between.

Everywhere I've looked says use the `random.nextInt` but that also chooses from the numbers in between -10 and 10...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try using

```
xSpeed = (random.nextInt() % 2 == 0) ? 10 : -10;
ySpeed = (random.nextInt() % 2 == 0) ? 10 : -10;
```

Good luck

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
if(random.nextBoolean()){
     xSpeed = 10;
}
else xSpeed = -10;
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this? `Math.random()` returns values between 0.0 (include) and 1.0 (exclude).

```
public class RandomTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int xSpeed = 0;
        int ySpeed = 0;

        if (Math.random() >= 0.5) {
            xSpeed = -10;
        } else {
            xSpeed = 10;
        }

        if (Math.random() >= 0.5) {
            ySpeed = -10;
        } else {
            ySpeed = 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets suppose your `random.nextInt(gameView.getHeight());` distributes evenly between even and odd numbers, then you could write something like this:

```
y = random.nextInt(gameView.getHeight()) % 2  == 0 ? 10 : -10;
```

Comment: random.nextInt(n) gives random number between 0 and n. It will never be distributed evenly between negative and positive numbers.